# How to duplicate div by checking box?

Tags: html, duplicates, clone, replicate

I want a user to be able to create an undetermined number of questions. Once a user has created one question I want another one (question 2) to appear and so on..

How would I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: You really need to elaborate a bit more on that!

Comment: So once a user enters the title and description into text boxes they click a text box to say its complete and another set of text boxes appears below so they can enter their second question. Once they've entered all the questions they can click a button to submit the data

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far and what part of it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this

HTML

```
<div class="input-container">
  <input class="question" placeholder="Question" type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="add-option">+</div>
```

JS

```
//click the '+' sign
$(".add-option").click(function(){

   //find the first input and clone it then append it to the container
   $(".input-container input:first").clone().appendTo(".input-container");

   //clear any value from the next input had there been any added
   $(".input-container input:last").val("");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cou7fqnq/)

**UPDATE**

I left out the part about the checkbox, from a UI perspective I don't think you need a checkbox to acomplish this, not sure it suggests "this is done and i want to move on" but that's up for you to decide. Here is a new fiddle

HTML

```
<div class="input-container">
  <input class="question" placeholder="Question" type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="add-option"><input type="checkbox"/></div>
```

JS

```
//click the checkbox
$(".add-option input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){

 //find the first input and clone it then append it to the container
 $(".input-container input:first").clone().appendTo(".input-container");

 //clear any value from the next input had there been any added
 $(".input-container input:last").val("");

 //reset the checkbox
 $(this).prop("checked", false);
});
```

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cou7fqnq/2/)

Comment: Nice thanks, what are the names of the duplicated text boxes?

Comment: @JoeTindall sorry typing too fast: you can name them anything that you want. You can add a unique name or number to them when you clone them, i overlooked the part about the checkbox, I updated my answer with a new fiddle

Comment: @JoeTindall you got it. Glad to help, can you mark this off as resolved when you can?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```js
function addClone() {
    var cloned = document.getElementById('test').cloneNode(true); //clone the element
    document.body.appendChild(cloned); //add the cloned element to the page
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>iadwjoam</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="xxx" name="xxx" onchange="addClone()" />
```

`cloneNode()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can do like this

```js
var i = 0;

function addMore() {
  i++;
  var parentDiv = document.createElement("div");

  var childLabel = document.createElement("label");
  childLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Enter Value " + i));

  var childTextBox = document.createElement("input");
  childTextBox.type = "text";
  childTextBox.id = "txtInput" + i;

  var childCheckBox = document.createElement("input");
  childCheckBox.type = "checkbox";
  childCheckBox.onchange = addMore;

  parentDiv.appendChild(childLabel);
  parentDiv.appendChild(childTextBox);
  parentDiv.appendChild(childCheckBox);
  document.body.appendChild(parentDiv);

}
```

```html
<div>
  Add Items
  <input type="checkbox" onchange="addMore()">
</div>
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Here's more or less what I would do using pure JavaScript (see comments for explanation)

```js
// Create a copy of a blank Question node
question_template = document.getElementById("questions").firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
// A nice cloning wrapper
new_question = function(){return question_template.cloneNode(true);};
// Something to do when the user is finished putting in questions
alrt = function(){
    alert(Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementById(
      "questions").getElementsByTagName("input"),
      function(elt){return elt.value;}));
};
// Hook for when text is placed in textbox
addnew = function(){
    // Remove the event listener (If you don't do this, then on every
    //   keystroke a new box will be created
    document.getElementById("questions").lastElementChild.oninput = function(event){};
    // Add a new line
    document.getElementById("questions").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    // Add a new question box
    document.getElementById("questions").appendChild(new_question());
};
```

```html
<div id="questions">
<input type="text" oninput="addnew()"/>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Done" onclick="alrt()"/>
```

**UPDATE:** I just saw your elaboration in the main post's comment section. You could implement that with something like this:

```js
// Create a copy of a blank Question node
question_template = document.getElementById("questions").firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
// A nice cloning wrapper
new_question = function(){return question_template.cloneNode(true);};
// Something to do when the user is finished putting in questions
alrt = function(){
    alert(Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementById(
      "questions").getElementsByTagName("input"),
      function(elt){return elt.value;}));
};
// Hook for when text is placed in textbox
addnew = function(){
    // Add a new line
    document.getElementById("questions").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    // Add a new question box
    document.getElementById("questions").appendChild(new_question());
};
```

```html
<div id="questions">
    <input type="text"/>
    </div>
<input type="button" value="Add Another" onclick="addnew()"/>
    <input type="button" value="Done" onclick="alrt()"/>
```

This can be implemented with most any `input` element with the right events. The W3 Schools has [a nice reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp), if you need it.